# Is it possible to use more than one framework at the backend(Spring boot + Django)?

Tags: java, python, django, spring, backend

**tl;dr: Is Spring + Django back-end possible?**

When I was new to industry and was still working my way around the office, I got interested in Django and created a very small, basic-level application using the framework. When I got to meet my team after a few weeks, they said to go for Spring framework. After spending half a year on the framework and the main proj, I finally started to get time to start working off-hours. But, I don't want to lose both the skills - My teammate(when we were still in office ;) ) once told me that they worked on a project that started with python code, and then later added features using Java. And I am unable to find any helpful google searches(mostly showing Spring vs Django).

How should I go about it? Is it too much to ask for? Is it worthwhile? Will I learn some new concepts of application architecture a noob like me would have missed. Please provide me with some insight.

Are there resources(docs) I can go through?

P.S. I'm not a diehard fan of either of the frameworks right now, just another coder testing waters.

Comment: There are 2 different frameworks for 2 different languages, what exactly are you asking? Whether it is possible to write a backend mixed in python and java? No if you mean mixing the code together.

Comment: I'm asking if it is possible to have backend with some features developed in django while some features are developed using spring boot. But when frontend asks for some data - all the features work in sync to process info.

"Mixing python and java is not possible - and this is not what I'm asking."

Comment: Developing different features usually implies in the container of the same app so no, it is not possible. You could develop different (independent) parts/modules of backend in any different languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write java in python.

You can extend Python with C/C++ which is quite common: [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html)

And about the part that they told that they added features with java:

It's common to create different parts of a project using different languages and tools. Microservice architecture is a common architecture for these kinds of use cases. You basically code different parts of the project in a language you want and then you connect all the parts using different methods like REST APIs, gRPC and etc.

Imagine you are creating a website like youtube that lets others upload videos. There is a form that users upload their files and you store them in your storage and then you have to encode the video file for different qualities. You can code the form handler using Python and Django to store the files in your storage. Then you can code another service using java that handles the encoding part which is a heavy process. When an upload is completed, you send the file or file path to your java service using an internal REST API and tell the service to start encoding the video and notify the Django service and then the Django service will publish the video on the feed that can itself be written in another language.

Answer (score 0):

I would say go for 1 framework and stick with it. For example Django if you want to code in python, and spring if you want to code in java. Learning both frameworks however brings a lot of value, because you can compare their benefits (eg. spring forces you to write clean code, django has build-in and simpler database management)

I like Django's build-in tooling a lot, you only need to know python for it to work. Spring requires a bit more knowledge of eg. hibernate for database management. However I predict Django will outgrow spring at some point, because of cloud valuing fast iteration over code and quick startup time (auto-scaling apps) over large overhead apps and long boot times. Hoever, if you like java, I can recommend JHipster for java/spring webapp development to get up to speed very fast and learning the ways of REST CRUD api fast.

To combine 2 programs: write your main logic in one app, and write a small service in the second language, making sure its independent of the first app (no back and forth communication and complicated logic, but simple independent request/response, as if the main app was never there). Add a REST api to the second app and use eg. http requests to communicate.

What's possible in terms of combining languages:

- connect different applications with each other: by letting them communicate through their APIs. For example a python api developed with flask or django can send requests to a java api developed with spring, as long as they have a way to communicate (eg over http, or via some queue like rabbitmq)
- connect a webapp to 2 different backends: by using a shared authentication system: For example a keycloak authentication server to handle tokens, that your backend applications know about.

What's not possible (and also not preferable):

- combining java with python code in the same program: there are some hacky ways to get it to work, but its asking for trouble and not readable.